# Strip and split based on keyword Python

Tags: python

I want to strip and split based on a keyword "**IsValid**" from the csv file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byj8JxXAeyj_elJPZ283N2FkRFk/view?usp=sharing). I dont understand why it doesn't split it with a comma delimeter after finding the keyword for dataString[1]. But dataString[0] seems to be done with the right output.

**Sample Data**

```
sampleData = 'DateTimeOfYCalibration,10/14/2015 11:13:28 AM, SpectrometerID,7a000001aa4fa22d\nYCalibration, Passed\nTemperature C ,9.1815\nPolynomial:,LC0,LC1,LC2,LC3,\nPolynomial:,0.998267689388189,-2.91917601399914E-07,3.58630729096524E-11,-8.13797132254045E-16,\nPixelIndex,Average Counts (Electric Dark Corrected),Average Counts Per Time,Max Counts Per Time,Standard Counts Per Time,Normalized Average Counts Per Time, Polynomial Index,Average Rate Below 3000, Fx, Residual,Smoothed residual,IsValid\n352,634.070221066319,121.91875734244,122.105500181174,121.895814648232,1.00018821560259,0,0.996183096974646,0.998096804243843,0.00209141135874924,0.000692356299613788,Valid,\n352,972.314,121.866186820435,122.105500181174,121.895814648232,0.999756941385704,0,0.996183096974646,0.998017010511045,0.00173993087465907,3.60232323325147E-06,Vali,\n919,28898.6315789474,140.969800979983,141.009749649689,140.915306078955,1.00038672094995,0,0.999291733917941,1.00014173653422,0.000244984415730176,0.000109783646710659,Valid,\n'
```

**Input**

```
dataString = sampleData.strip().split("IsValid")
```

**Obtained output for dataString[0]**

```
In [39]: dataString[0]
Out[39]: 'DateTimeOfYCalibration,10/14/2015 11:13:28 AM, SpectrometerID,7a000001aa4fa22d\nYCalibration, Passed\nTemperature C ,9.1815\nPolynomial:,LC0,LC1,LC2,LC3,\nPolynomial:,0.998267689388189,-2.91917601399914E-07,3.58630729096524E-11,-8.13797132254045E-16,\nPixelIndex,Average Counts (Electric Dark Corrected),Average Counts Per Time,Max Counts Per Time,Standard Counts Per Time,Normalized Average Counts Per Time, Polynomial Index,Average Rate Below 3000, Fx, Residual,Smoothed residual,'
```

**Obtained output for dataString[1]**

```
'\n352,634.070221066319,121.91875734244,122.105500181174,121.895814648232,1.00018821560259,0,0.996183096974646,0.998096804243843,0.00209141135874924,0.000692356299613788,Valid,\n352,972.314,121.866186820435,122.105500181174,121.895814648232,0.999756941385704,0,0.996183096974646,0.998017010511045,0.00173993087465907,3.60232323325147E-06,Valid'
```

**Expected output for dataString[1]:**

```
'\n352,634.070221066319,121.91875734244,122.105500181174,121.895814648232,1.00018821560259,0,0.996183096974646,0.998096804243843,0.00209141135874924,0.000692356299613788,Valid,\n352,972.314,121.866186820435,122.105500181174,121.895814648232,0.999756941385704,0,0.996183096974646,0.998017010511045,0.00173993087465907,3.60232323325147E-06,Valid,'
```

Comment: Please post sample data.  Your link doesn't provide a direct path to the data; it appears to require an account and/or download to my disk.

Comment: I have included a sample data as a minimum working example. The output for dataString[1] seems to be the problem.

Comment: When I run your code, I get dataString[1] as having the final comma and newline.  Please note that there's one more line of data in your input, not represented in your obtained and expected output lines.  It would also help if you would pare this to a minimal example: having output 4 sliders wide doesn't help the readability, and is unrelated to the problem at hand.  See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last comma should still be included in dataString[1]. This is because the strip function without an argument should only remove whitespace (not commas). Then, the split function splits by "IsValid." If you wanted to remove any leading or trailing commas and also any whitespace, you can do something like this (with a shorter text example).

```
 sample=',,,,Hello,1,2,,,,,  '
 sample.strip(', ')
```

to get

```
 'Hello,1,2'
```